# Camera turn ON takes more time when inserted in other thread

Tags: android, android-camera

I am writing the strobe light code for android.Samsung galaxy ace does not support flash mode.So I wrote it on my own. Here is the code which I am using to make it a strobe light.
But it block the main thread of the android application(UI thread) , which I do not want to happen.When I insert this code in new thread and run it , the ON period is more when I measure it. Why is it so ?

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();     
Camera.Parameters pon = cam.getParameters(); 
Camera.Parameters poff = cam.getParameters();

while(true) {
    try {           
        //d = new Date();                           
        //System.out.println("ON START " + d.getSeconds());

        cam.setParameters(pon);
        //because FLASH_MODE_TORCH isnt supported
        pon.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON); 
        pon.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);                

        s1.start();
        cam.startPreview();         
        cam.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                camera.autoFocus(this);
            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(500);
        //d = new Date();
        s1.stop();
        System.out.println("ON FOR milliseconds : " + s1.getElapsedTime());                         
        cam.stopPreview();

        s2.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);                          
        s2.stop();
        System.out.println("OFF FOR milliseconds : " + s2.getElapsedTime());                            
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

I just insert the above code in new runnable and say start, the ON period is more when it is inserted in a thread. Elapsed time is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use message handler or async task. 
See [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)